# Android MapFragment not calling OnMapReadyCallback

Tags: android, callback, mapfragment

I have a simple Android application with an app drawer, which selects fragments within my activity. When I select the map fragment no map is shown because it never gets ready. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.tanktoo.eventreporter;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

EventMapFragment mapFragment;
boolean mapReady = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    this.mapFragment = new EventMapFragment();
    this.mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    System.out.println("map" + this.mapFragment);
}


    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        System.out.println("###############");
        this.mapReady = true;
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
        System.out.println("reeady " + this.mapReady);
        if(this.mapReady){
            fragment = this.mapFragment;
        }
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_report_event) {
        fragment = new ReportEventFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_config) {
        fragment = new ConfigFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_user) {
        fragment = new UserFragment();
    }
    if(fragment != null) {
        System.out.println("select: " + fragment);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

This is the java class (EventMapFragment.java) for the map fragment:

```
package com.example.tanktoo.eventreporter;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class EventMapFragment extends MapFragment {


public EventMapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eventmap, container, false);
}

}
```

And this is the layout file fragment_eventmap.xml:

```
< FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tanktoo.eventreporter.EventMapFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/eventmap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tanktoo.eventreporter">

    <permission android:name="com.example.tanktoo.eventreporter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.tanktoo.eventreporter.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="KEY...kY"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So my problem is that the Callback method is never called and mapReady stays at false the whole time. Can anybody help me? Don't know if it right to add the map fragment in the layout file too.
The map service itself is running within the application. I have tested it with setting a map fragment (not my extended class) on the main screen just within the layout of the MainActivity. This works fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post your Manifest..

Comment: Added the Manifest :)

Comment: please Address this Guide.. your missing few things on the Manifiest https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config#specify_android_permissions

Comment: I have added 
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
Dont see anything else missing... not working with these additional lines.

Comment: have you added the OpenGL meta data?